# XML File using PHP - Altering the First Two Lines UTF-8

Tags: php, xml, encoding

I have an XML file which is formatted in a specific way with specific nodes. I have the following PHP code (in test.php) to create a new XML file each week or else append the XML file if an entry is within the same week;

```
$filename = date('Y-W').'.xml'; //2014-26.xml

//Check if a file exists
if (file_exists($filename)) 
    {
    // call xml appendFile function
    appendFile($filename);
    }
else 
    {
    // call xml createFile function
    createFile($filename);
    }
```

When a new file is created (e.g. 2014-26.xml), the top two lines of the XML file are as follows;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<entry>
```

I need the top two lines to be;

```
<?xml version=”1.0” encoding=”UTF-8”?>
<Document xmlns=”urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02” xmlns:xsi=”http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance”>
```

In my test.php file, I have the following function which is causing the "entry" node to be displayed;

```
function addRoot(&$xml)
{
    $xml->appendChild($xml->createElement("entry"));
}
```

I call this function within the createFile function as follows;

```
// create a root element, and add it to DOM
    addRoot($xml);
```

I tried simply changing "entry" to the second line which I require but I received an error. Anybody have any ideas as to how I would change these top two lines to suit my requirements as I have been attempting for days to no avail? I am very new to XML. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to Part 1;

I fixed the first line by entering adding "UTF-8" to this line of code as follows;

```
// create new dom document
    $xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
```

Solution to Part 2;

On the off chance that anyone else may have this problem, I was able to put the second line in by altering this code to;

```
function addRoot(&$xml)
{   
    $root = $xml->createElementNS('urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02', 'Document');
    $xml->appendChild($root);
    $root->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/' ,'xmlns:xsi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
}
```